# When I use a redirect() function in my code before the php mail() function, will the mail be sent? am using joomla v1.5

Tags: php, joomla-api, emails, joomla-1.5

I am using Joomla 1.5 and I would like to know if my mail will be sent if I run the function after `redirect();`

My code is as below:

```
$callback   = new stdClass();
$callback->LeaveID    = $leaveid;
$callback->callback   = 1;
$callback->balance_cf = $balance_cf;
$callback->remarks    = $remarks;

if($db->updateObject('#__leaves',$callback,'LeaveID')) {
  $app->redirect($url,' Callback Perfomed Successfully');
} 
else {
  echo 'Not saved - Leave App';
}

mail($user->email,$somesubject,$message,implode("\r\n",$headers));`
```

Will the mail function be executed if the `$db->updateObject()` returns `true`?

Comment: Why do you want to execute the `mail()` function after the redirect? Can you not put it inside the `if` statement and redirect if the mail if successful?

Comment: i want the mail to be sent no matter the outcome of the `if(){}` block

Comment: In which case, you can send the mail **before** the `if` statement

Comment: i fear `mail()` using up all the resources before trying the `update`..that's why am running it `after`

Comment: I'll compile an answer for you in a minute

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using the PHP mail function, I'll show you how to use Joomla's `JMail` class. We'll also make sure that the email is always sent and the database is updated after:

```
$callback             = new stdClass();
$callback->LeaveID    = $leaveid;
$callback->callback   = 1;
$callback->balance_cf = $balance_cf;
$callback->remarks    = $remarks;

// Let's firstly send the email
$mail = &JFactory::getMailer();
$mail->setSubject($somesubject);
$mail->setSender('me@example.com');
$mailer->addRecipient('to@example.com');
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->setBody($message);

$send = $mail->Send();

if ($send == true)
{
    // The email was sent, so we can now do the database updates
    if ($db->updateObject('#__leaves', $callback, 'LeaveID'))
    {
        $app->redirect($url, 'Callback Perfomed Successfully');
    } 
    else
    {
        echo 'Not saved - Leave App';
    }
} 
else
{
    // Error sending the email
    echo 'Error sending email: ' . $send->__toString();
}
```

Hope this helps.

**Note:** I may have accidentally made a small mistake as it's been a long time since I've written any code for the old Joomla 1.5, but hopefully it will push you in the right direction

Comment: does this work in j1.5? I use this in v3.*

Comment: @PatrickMutwiri - I'm not sure about your database update query (`updateObject`), but the mail should work. Like I said, it's been a long time since I wrote any code for Joomla 1.5......I only use 3.x these days which is quite different

Answer (score 0):

Your Question:

> Will the mail function be executed if the $db->updateObject() returns
>   true?

Answer: **No.**

If you want to execute functions before returns or redirects put them just before such statements.

> i fear mail() using up all the resources before trying the update..that's why am running it after –

This shouldn't happen unless your host server is from the 80s or you have just < 16 MB RAM.

**Recommendations**

Please switch to the latest Joomla, don't use deprecated software. Your site is vulnerable to hacks, and puts your visitors to unnecessary risk.

Use the native Joomla mailer lib.

If you are using dynamically generated recipient lists (like sending a mail from a contact form), limit the max recipients.

**Use $db->quote()** for inserting data or at least **htmlspecialchars**.